# Counting folders within a folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Does anyone know a code I can use to count the number of folders in a specified directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The very simplest code that I know of uses `TDirectory` from the `IOUtils` unit:

```
function GetDirectoryCount(const DirName: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(TDirectory.GetDirectories(DirName));
end;
```

`TDirectory.GetDirectories` actually returns a dynamic array containing the names of the directories so this is somewhat inefficient. If you want the most efficient solution then you should use `FindFirst` to enumerate.

```
function GetDirectoryCount(const DirName: string): Integer;
var
  res: Integer;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  Name: string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  res := FindFirst(TPath.Combine(DirName, '*'), faAnyFile, SearchRec);
  if res=0 then begin
    try
      while res=0 do begin
        if SearchRec.FindData.dwFileAttributes and faDirectory<>0 then begin
          Name := SearchRec.FindData.cFileName;
          if (Name<>'.') and (Name<>'..') then begin
            inc(Result);
          end;
        end;
        res := FindNext(SearchRec);
      end;
    finally
      FindClose(SearchRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: David, why do you use _faAnyFile_ and not _faDirectory_ within the `FindFirst`?

Comment: @Whiler I want to include read only objects, hidden objects, system objects.

Comment: @David, isn't there a possible leak if GetDirectoryCount is zero ? Documentation says only to call FindClose if a matching FindFirst is ok.

Comment: @LU RD Yes I think you are right. I was being lazy. Is it better now?

Comment: if the folder exists, there are at least 2 results: . & .. ;o) or is it possible to not have them in some specific cases?

Comment: yes.. but FindFirst returns them... so, no issue with FindClose?

Comment: @Whiler I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I speak about the leak issue exposed by LU RD... I think, this is not possible in your context...

Comment: @Whiler in the original version, before I edited, it called FindClose even if FindFirst returned non-zero. According to specs that is an error.

Comment: @LU RD, David: **Documentation is outdated**. You can always call SysUtils.FindClose since, IIRC, Delphi 6 or Delphi 7. FindClose will do nothing if FindFirst did not find anything. This ought to be documented, IIRC.

Comment: @Rudy, interesting. I checked D2007-XE2 and source/documentation says what you are saying, yet all code examples for the same versions show as I and David proposed. I will make crash test, since I remember there was an issue on D2007 when refactoring code.

Comment: @Rudy, if FindFirst fails, it will internally call FindClose. So the code presented here is correct.

Comment: @Rudy You are correct that FindClose can be called even if FindFirst returns non-zero. However, the try/finally defends against exceptions being raised between FindFirst and FindClose.